# Temporarily switch view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my problem is that I have a controller in which I call a function which basically does an http call returning a promise.

Sample controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    MyService.doHttp().then(function(result) {
        handleMyData(result);
    });
});
```

During the http call I'd like to show a 'loading' view/partial which contains a loading spinner and then forward to another view when the request is finally completed.
How could I do such thing? thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I handle this is, on my root `index.html` page, I have something like this:

```
<div class="modal-loading" ng-show="loading"></div>
```

Then, I set a `loading` property on `$rootScope` when something is loading, and hide it when the loading is done.

```
(function(app) {
    app.controller(‘MyController’, [‘$scope’, ‘$rootScope’, '$location', ‘MyService’, 
          function($scope, $rootScope, $location, MyService) {

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $rootScope.loading = true;

        MyService.doHttp().then(function(result) {
           handleMyData(result);
           $rootScope.loading = false;
           $location.path('/anotherView');
        }); 
      }
    });

})(angular.module(‘app’));
```

And for reference, the css of for modal-loading is like this, which overlays the whole screen with a lighter color and has a spinner gif in the middle

```
.modal-loading {
  display: block;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('../images/ajax-loader.gif') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Boolean in scope, hide/show loader using flag

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.showLoader = true; //using rootScope so that html code can be put anywhere in app
    MyService.doHttp().then(function(result) {
        handleMyData(result);
        $rootScope.showLoader = false;
    });
});
```

Add loader code in html:

```
<div ng-show="showLoader" >
   loader content here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for support, however I find that Tom's answer is more suitable in this case.